# Symbol or Convention for Representing Endianness?

Tags: endianness

Is there a symbol, or some other convention, for indicating the endianness of a value/variable/what-have-you in technical writing?

That is, if I wanted to describe an algorithm or formula, and represent that formula as a mathematical expression (e.g. X = P + 2 / Y), is there a way of indicating the endianness of one of the variables?

For example:

> The following formula shows you how to calculate a the new pointer value, `npnt`.
>
> When working with the old pointer value, stored in the `INT` variable `pnt`, keep in mind that it is stored little-endian, while `new` and `offset` are big endian.  In order to perform mathematical operations using the value of `pnt`, you must change `pnt` to be big-endian.
>
> `INT pnt = 0x1722`
>
> `INT new = 0x900F`
>
> `INT offset = 0xF600`
>
> `npnt = offset + new - pnt`

This is just a random example.  The main thing I am concerned with is the formula itself - without the paragraph explanation above, there is no indication of the endianness of each variable in the formula.

The solution I came up with would be to superscript an arrow symbol to the variables like so:

> npnt<sup>→</sup> = offset<sup>→</sup> + new<sup>→</sup> - pnt<sup>←</sup>

Or, better yet, put the arrows directly above the variable names (which I can't quite do using the limited HTML of SO).

Is there a convention for that?  Or is this something that is just never done because I'm describing/representing things wrong in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a cross-platform code base I worked on, I used the convention of appending `_be` to variables in big-endian byte order and `_le` for those in little-endian byte order.  Anything else was assumed to be in host byte order.

Structures created for networking protocols used that naming, so it was very clear what byte order you were dealing with.  We had to deal with both big and little endian values, and sticking to this convention helped greatly.

If you're consistent, it's very hard to make mistakes in your code.  Assigning `foo_be` to `bar` sticks out as wrong, and `bar = be16toh( foo_be)` just looks right.

If you're using formatted text, you could use a sub-scripted `be` or `le` on any value or variable not in host byte order.

Comment: Not sure no one ever gave you credit for this idea. It clarifies the nature of variables in use (and facilitates making wrong code [b]wrong[/b] as suggested by Spolsky : http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html

Comment: Thanks for including the link to Joel's article on this topic.